Python 3.13 now segfaults when running pyprimesieve
I am running Python 3.13, installed using HomeBrew, in a venv on a Mac (M2 Air, MacOS14.5). When I upgraded from 3.12 to 3.13 (at least I think this is what caused the issue), pyprimesieve now segfaults in the primesieve code.
python
Python 3.13.0 (main, Oct  7 2024, 05:02:14) [Clang 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyprimesieve import primes
>>> primes(14)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
>>> primes(20)
zsh: segmentation fault  python

I am using pyprimesieve 0.1.6, and the two relevant entries in the site-packages in my venv are
pyprimesieve-0.1.6.dist-info/
pyprimesieve.cpython-313-darwin.so*

I'm not sure what other information is relevant, but here is my pyvenv.cfg file:
home = /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.13/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.13.0
executable = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/bin/python3.13
command = /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.13/bin/python3.13 -m venv /Users/rlipsett/Dropbox/Math/EulerProject/.venv

Any help would be very welcome.
